# The type com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener cannot be resolved

Tags: java, libgdx

Today ,when i opened eclipse suddenly this error appeared in one of my libgdx projects

**Code:**

```
public static void main (String[] argv) {
    if (application == null) {
        application = new Main();
    }

    LwjglApplicationConfiguration conf=new LwjglApplicationConfiguration() ;
    conf.title="XXXXXApp";
    conf.width=(int)(480/1.3f);
    conf.height=(int)(800/1.3f);
    conf.useGL20=false;

    new LwjglApplication(new XXXXXApp(application,new DesktopInterface()), conf);
}
```

**Error:**

```
-The type com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
-The constructor LwjglApplication(ApplicationListener, LwjglApplicationConfiguration) refers to the missing type ApplicationListener
```

I double checked for missing jars and everything are the same as  my other projects that are working and they use exactly the same code .

**What i tried:**

- Restart eclipse
- Remove and add again the libdgx jars
- Refresh

The jars that are right now in my build path are:

```
-gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar
-gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar
-gdx-natives.jar
```

Comment: Do you have the main project referenced? And also try to delete the project and re-import it again. This helped me very often...

Comment: @noone , yep the main project is referenced and i tried deleting and re-importing all the projects (android,main,desktop)

Comment: Are you sure you still have the correct `import`, maybe it got lost or it's importing an ApplicationListener from a package that doesn
t exist? Try adding gdx.jar as well, that's the package which should contain the ApplicationListener.

Comment: @noone ,Oh  you are right, it seems i had to add the gdx.jar to the desktop project.Strange since its not added in my other working projects. Nevermind .If you want ,post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the completion of this question:

In general, use this program to setup your libgdx projects, or create a quick dummy project and check the configuration to correct your other projects, since it should always generate a working example project: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew

To resolve this error, reference gdx.jar in the project where ApplicationListener cannot be resolved. Sometimes it's also a problem with Eclipse and deleting and re-importing the project can help to solve the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem - other projects were correctly working while the one I just created was not. Couldn't figure out why.

Turns out the problem was related to the "Game" project - and not the Game-desktop that was reporting the error. LIBGDX Setup creates the following:
Game
Game-android
Game-desktop/html/ios

One solution is to import the GDX library in the desktop, android, html and ios files. This forces you to change all the projects, not sure how it impacts the final JAR.

The best solution in my opinion is to go into Eclipse "Game" Project properties, Java Build Path, Order and Export and make sure the GDX library jar is checked for export. 
This will fix the issue and your Game-(anyos) will compile correctly without the need for importing the GDX library in each of them.